The minimum product of the diagonals of a PSD matrix under orthogonal transformations
Let $D = diag(d_1,\dots,d_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a diagonal matrix such that $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \dots \ge d_n > 0$, and let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an arbitrary orthogonal matrix, i.e., $U^T U =I$, then it seems to hold that
$\prod_{j=1}^r d_j \leq \prod_{j=1}^r (u_j^TDu_j),$ for $r = 1,\dots,n$.
Or to say, the minimum of the following optimization problem is attained when $U=I$,
$\min \{\prod_{j=1}^r a_{jj}:A=U^TDU,U^T U =I \}$.
I have verified the above inequality by Matlab, but how to prove it mathematically?

Probably you meant the maximum, not minimum

This is not true already for 2x2 matrices. Just take a matrix with eigenvalues 1 and $\epsilon$ very close to zero.

oh, yes. The maximum, thanks.

@Exodd Thanks. That’s a typo. By Hadamard’s determinantal inequality for PSD matrices, we always have $\det A\le\prod_ia_{ii}$. So, the direction of the inequality in the OP’s question should be reversed.

@user1551 Thanks for refering to the Hadmard inequality.
